# Bean property 'contracts[0].conid()' is not readable or has an invalid getter method - Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin

I am trying to pass an object to thymeleaf and then return it back in my Kotlin spring boot application. The contractForm will contain 7 items in the contracts list. Am I doing something wrong with the setup of the data class or the th:name or other?

Calling function

```
@GetMapping("/search")
    fun helloWorld(@RequestParam sourceText: String, model: Model) : String {

        val contracts = symbolService.findSymbol(sourceText)
        val contractForm = ContractForm(contracts)
        model.addAttribute("form", contractForm)

        println("Returned from search")
        println(contracts)

        return "index"
    }
```

Model for the contractForm

```
data class ContractForm(var contracts: List<Contract>?) : Contract() {
}
```

Form method in the thymeleaf template

```
<form th:action="@{/search/save}"  method="POST" th:object="${form}">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" th:value="Save">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>conid</th>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>type</th>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th>Primary ex.</th>
            <th>save</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="contract, itemStat : *{contracts}">
            <td><input type="text" th:name="*{contracts[__${itemStat.index}__].conid}" th:field="*{contracts[__${itemStat.index}__].conid}" th:value="${contract.conid}" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:name="*{contracts[__${itemStat.index}__].symbol}" th:field="*{contracts[__${itemStat.index}__].symbol}" th:value="${contract.symbol}" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:name="*{contracts[__${itemStat.index}__].secType}" th:field="*{contracts[__${itemStat.index}__].secType}" th:value="${contract.secType}" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:name="*{contracts[__${itemStat.index}__].currency}" th:field="*{contracts[__${itemStat.index}__].currency}" th:value="${contract.currency}" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:name="*{contracts[__${itemStat.index}__].primaryExch}" th:field="*{contracts[__${itemStat.index}__].primaryExch}" th:value="${contract.primaryExch}" /></td>

        </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Error message:

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 23, col 88)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 23, col 88)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.processIterationModel(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:367)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:221)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:322)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:220)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:164)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'contracts[0].conid' of bean class [com.sg.robotproxy.controller.ContractForm]: Bean property 'contracts[0].conid' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Comment: There's not enough information to know what is going on, but my guess is that `Contract` object does not have a field called `conid`.  If you want more help  1) what fields does `Contract` have in it?

2) assuming `Contract` is a data class it will have automatic toString that will show the fields, so can you share the output of the`println(contracts)` as this show the fields and their data

Comment: After much investigation it seems like there was a problem for the template engine to understand the object sent back when I embedded the input elements in different TDs. I also built a class containing only the fields that I was sharing with thymeleaf.